# modify PHPList email headers, create minimal email headers

Tags: phplist

PHPList sends email with very complex email-headers.  They insert links and messages and notices and all kinds of headers that aren't needed.

Does anyone know the filenames and lines of code to edit to remove everything except the bare minimum email headers?

I don't care why they are they I, personally, only want the bare minimum email headers.

I was able to find a way to edit some of them to remove only a few of the unnecessary headers but not all of them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible, you should write a plugin to provide edited fields for your emails header.
you can start by implementing the plugin `messageHeaders()`

```
     /**
   * messageHeaders
   * return headers for the message to be added, as "key => val"
   * @param object $mail
   * @return array (headeritem => headervalue)
   */
  function messageHeaders($mail) {
    return array();
  }
```

Here is the post discussing the subject: edit emails header for phpList

Setting up custom email headers https://discuss.phplist.org/t/setting-up-custom-email-headers-is-it-possible/977

Another post about adding custom header fields :
can check here https://forums.phplist.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=24474&p=91989&hilit=unsubscribe+header#p91989